# I want to see the product_name. Error is - Property [product_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (abc.blade.php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, laravel-blade

```
@foreach ($alldata as $value)
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab_1" aria-controls="tab_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    {{ $value->product->product_name}} 
    <!-- Error on this line -->
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_2" aria-controls="tab_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab_1">Content 1</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2">Content 2</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please add the database structure of the product table, are you sure there is a field called `product_name` and that it is not simply called `name`? Please also add the controller method . And add the `dd($alldata)`.

Answer (score -1):

Where your defined your product relation is probably set up incorrectly in your model as currently it is returning a collection (if your relation 'product' is returning a collection you'd see this error)

I assume you'd probably want a hasOne or belongsTo relationship, which both return a single model instance